# Merging identical result sets from multiple tables into a single result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I could use a little help on a MySQL database issue I am dealing with. I have gone through a bunch of old answers to almost the same question, - but have had no luck sofar. Some of the answers seem like it is what I need (JOIN, INNER JOIN, JOIN LEFT), - but still doesnt give me the correct output. I got either a weird output or a plain error-message...

OK here goes:

I have 4 tables - and they all contain the same number of fields - with the same name. So 4 different tables with duplicate fields.

I need to fetch everything from all 4 tables where field eid=219, into one array, .

I need to be able to limit the output to 20 rows - so I can display them on separate pages. Which means the starting point will be different depending on current page...

Any idea how to go about this?

Lets say that the tables are:

table1
table2
table3
table4

And they all contain the fields:
id
eid
name
tekst

Thx
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a UNION query:

```
(SELECT id, eid, name, tekst, 'from table 1' as table_source FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT id, eid, name, tekst, 'from table 2' as table_source FROM table2)
UNION
(SELECT id, eid, name, tekst, 'from table 3' as table_source FROM table3)
UNION
(SELECT id, eid, name, tekst, 'from table 4' as table_source FROM table4)
ORDER BY name LIMIT 20
```

Comment: However, I now realize that I have new problem then: Do I have any way of telling which row is from which table?

Comment: Check the edited answer. You can just throw any text you want in as a column. So change the table_source static value to whatever you need to differentiate the tables.

Comment: Using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` may speed up this query.